# "'int' object has no attribute 'getal'" in self made class Python

Tags: python, string, class, int

The idea of the program is to take a "language" and turn it into numbers. The language is build quite easy

> K = 10
>   P = 20
>   T = 40
>   V = 80
>   anything smaller then 10 will be represented in normal numbers

Now the numbers shouldn't be something to worry about I explain this so it's easier to get what I try to achieve here.

I build up a class called "Mangarevaans" which looks as following:

```
def mag2arab(getal):    #this function is designed to turn the letters into the normal numbers we're used to 
mag = str(getal)
waarde = {"K": 10, "P": 20, "T": 40, "V": 80}
arab = 0

for index, j in enumerate(mag):
    if index == 0 and j.isnumeric():

        if len(getal) == 1:
            x = 0
        else:
            x = 1

        arab += int(j) * waarde[mag[x]]
    elif j.isnumeric():
        arab += int(j)
    elif not (str(mag[0]).isnumeric() and index == 1):
        arab += waarde[j]
return arab

class Mangarevaans():
    """
    >>>612 // Mangarevaans(26)
    Mangarevaans('P3')
    """

    def __init__(self, getal):

        if isinstance(getal, int):
            assert 1 <= getal < 799, 'ongeldige waarde'   #this is one of the rules of the language that if there is a number it should be between these values
            self.getal = getal


        else:
            for letter in getal:
                if isinstance(getal, str):
                    for letter in getal:
                        if letter in "VTPK":
                            self.getal = getal
                else:
                    raise AssertionError('ongeldige waarde')
            self.getal = mag2arab(getal)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.getal

    def __str__(self):
        return arab2mag(self.getal)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Mangarevaans('{str(arab2mag(self.getal))}')"

    def __rfloordiv__(other, self):
        return Mangarevaans(other // self.getal) #The problem occurs here
```

Now when I want to run the doctest

```
    """
    >>>612 // Mangarevaans(26)
    Mangarevaans('P3')
    """
```

I get an error saying

> 'int' object has no attribute 'getal'

but if I change my self to a string I get

> 'str' object has no attribute 'getal'

how can i define if the attribute "getal" belongs with "str" or "int" ?

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks a lot already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is always the first argument, even in the `r*` (right) methods. So write:

```
def __rfloordiv__(self, other):
    return Mangarevaans(other // self.getal)
```

instead of:

```
def __rfloordiv__(other, self):
    return Mangarevaans(other // self.getal)
```

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you have the privilege to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). ;)

Comment: Hey that didn't work before because I wasn't "experienced" enough :D

Comment: Yes, accepting an answer gives you points that increase your reputation and might bring you over this limit.